# google docs not works in ie6

Tags: html, iframe, google-docs

```
<?php
$url="http://www.tnpsc.gov.in/Notifications/257_not_eng_grp2k11.pdf";
$url_test=urlencode($url);
?>
<iframe style="border-style: none;" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo $url_test; ?>&embedded=true" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

iframe displays the pdf content. but the code doesnt work with ie6. 
ie6 displays nothing inside iframe.

**How to display pdf content using google doc in ie6**

Comment: Get a real browser. IE6 is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 is not supported by Google Docs

See the "System requirements" for more details:
http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37560

Not even Microsoft supports IE6 any longer for a lot of reasons. So you should migrate to a supported Browser as soon as possible

Comment: well IE6 is supported on XP as long as XP is supported, that's how microsoft do things.

Comment: IE6 will only be supported With XP and SP**2**. But as far as I remember, support for SP2 is somewhat limited and as soon as SP3 is installed, there is no support for IE6 any longer (because SP3 ships with IE7). Anyhow: I6 should be considered dead :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really must use IE6, try installing the [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/)
It essentially embeds Google Chrome into IE.